# returns string that does not contain the substring in the list negative regex

Tags: python, string, substring, regex-negation

I need to **create a list or return a non-empty variable that contains characters different from the words that are in the list, I thought of regex**, but how do I do it?? Bellow, I show an example.

**Example 1:**

```
lista_ok = ['EXECUCAO OK','EXECUÇÃO OK',' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']

x = " ['EXECUCAO OK', ' Não existe a apólice informada'] " # (string)
```

`Output: ' Não existe a apólice informada'`

**Example 2:**

```
x = " [Nº da Apólice já cadastrada', 'EXECUCAO OK', ' Não existe a apólice informada'] " # (string)
```

`Output: ' Não existe a apólice informada'`

**Example 3:**

```
x = " ['EXECUCAO OK'] " or "[Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']" or "['EXECUCAO OK',' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']" # (string)
```

`Output: Empty or " "`

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse `x` into a list. Then you can just return the list element that's not in `lista_ok`. There's no need for a regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.litera_eval` to transform `x` to a python list, then keep the words not in `lista_ok`

```
def main(values_ok, value):
    words = ast.literal_eval(value)
    return " ".join([word for word in words if word not in values_ok])


lista_ok = ['EXECUCAO OK', 'EXECUÇÃO OK', ' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']

print(main(lista_ok, " ['EXECUCAO OK', ' Não existe a apólice informada'] "))
#  Não existe a apólice informada
print(main(lista_ok, " [' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada', 'EXECUCAO OK', ' Não existe a apólice informada'] "))
#  Não existe a apólice informada
print(main(lista_ok, " ['EXECUCAO OK'] "))
print(main(lista_ok, "[' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']"))
print(main(lista_ok, "['EXECUCAO OK',' Nº da Apólice já cadastrada']"))
```

---

To get a list of words :

```
return [word for word in words if word not in values_ok]
```

To get a string of them

```
return " ".join([word for word in words if word not in values_ok])
```